# Get event detail from google calendar private xml address

Tags: php, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I am using full calender in my website and with the help of Google calendar private XML address, i am fetching all events from my Google calendar and showing it on full calendar but i don't want to show all events instead i want to show/get events whose show me as option is set as "Available".

so is there any way that i can get detail of each event using Google calendar private XML address.

Comment: How about some code of things you already tried?

Comment: when you use Google calendar private xml address then you don't need any code. It automatically shows all events on full calendar. I have also tried Google calendar V3 Api but it was not suitable in my case

Comment: my basic purpose is to separate available and busy slots